# Why my computer declined my requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, stanford-nlp

```
from stanza.nlp.corenlp import CoreNLPClient
client = CoreNLPClient(server='http://localhost:9000', default_annotators=['ssplit', 'tokenize', 'lemma', 'pos', 'ner'])
annotated = client.annotate('This is an example document. Here is a second sentence')
for sentence in annotated.sentences:
print('sentence', sentence)
for token in sentence:
    print(token.word, token.lemma, token.pos, token.ner)
```

Error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000180C85765F8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 由于目标计算机积极拒绝，无法连接。
```

I am learning the python code of Stanford coreNlp. But my first trial is failed as stated above. I do not know anything about httpconnection, but I think this error means my computer(localhost) declined my requests. But why?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You sure you've a server listening for connections at localhost port 9000?

Comment: I am not sure. can you teach me how to check this?